# Download Excel not working in IPad

Tags: excel, ipad, safari

I am downloading excel file (.xlsx) .I am using

response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName+"\"");

the file is not password protected and it is downloading in all browser and in MAC system also but in IPad it is throwing (OfficeImportErrorDomain error 912)
I have the latest version of iPad and safari but still only in IPad it is not downloading.

Can anyone help me out on this issue